# Insert an auto-incremented primary key into an Access table

Tags: ms-access, primary-key

We have a giant table in an Access database with over 500k records and no PK. Is it possible to insert an auto-incrementing primary key column into an already existing Access table?

Comment: Yes. But more importantly I suggest you first identify a suitable key among the existing columns and de-duplicate the table if necessary. Adding an arbitrary key to a table in which you don't know how to identify data is just like sweeping the problem under the carpet.

Comment: Natural vs Surrogate argument, one side http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/10/06/Why-I-prefer-surrogate-keys-instead-of-natural-keys-in.aspx

Comment: @Remou, Nothing to do with "natural vs surrogate". Adding a surrogate key doesn't remove the need to ensure quality, non-redundant data and a meaningful key by which users can identify the information of interest to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is and can be done quite simply by editing the table and adding an autoincrement type field. The only rule is that you can only have one autoincrement per table.

[image: autoincrement]